# CSS Flexbox on mobile messes up boxes

Tags: html, css

I am working on converting over to Flexbox and struggle a lot.  With the help of SO, I was able to get started and now struggle with another part.  Everything works perfectly, so far, except when I view the page on iPhone 4 or Samsung 3, it messes up.  On the desktop, I can resize and everything is peachy, mobile, well, it doesn't work so well.  I have reduced as much as possible to make it shorter for here.  The logo works fine, it is the head_Area and head_Note that drop underneath the Logo which I obviously. don't want.  I am sure this is a simple fix, but daunting for me at the moment.  Any help would be great appreciated.

```css
*
{
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body,address,blockquote,div,
form,fieldset,caption,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
hr,ul,li,ol,ul,dd,dt,
table,tr,td,th,p,img
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

img,fieldset
{
   border: none;
}

body
{
   color: #CF6;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-size: 1.0em;
   max-width: 1280px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-family: "Tahoma", Verdana, sans-serif;
   background: #777 url(../homepics/homeback.jpg) top center;
}

#head_Main
{
   height: 112px;
   margin-bottom: -112px;
   border: 2px solid #444;
   background: #555 url(../homepics/homemenu2.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}

#head_Wrap
{
   width: 92%;
   display: flex;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 84em;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#head_Logo
{
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 77px;
   height: 90px;
   height: 112px;
   background: url(../homepics/homelogo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#head_Area
{
   flex: 2;
   display: flex;
   min-width: 5em;
   flex-direction: column;
}

#head_Info
{
   color: #0FF;
   height: 45px;
   font: normal 125%/45px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#head_News
{
   margin-top: 0;
   padding: 0 10px;
   font-weight: 600;
}

#head_News li
{
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#head_Note
{
   top: 0;
   width: 77px;
   height: 112px;
}



@media (max-width: 40em)
{

   #head_Main
   {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 1px solid pink;
   }

   #head_Wrap
   {
      width: 100%;
   }

   #head_Logo
   {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
   }

   #head_Area
   {
      flex: auto;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      border: 1px solid red;
   }

   .head_Menu
   {
      border: 1px solid blue;
   }

   #head_Info
   {
      border: 1px solid cyan;
   }

   #head_Note
   {
      border: 1px solid orange;
   }
}
```

```html
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>


   <body>
      <!-- header -->
      <header id="head_Main">
         <section id="head_Wrap">

            <article id="head_Logo">
            </article>

            <article id="head_Area">
               <div id="head_Info">
                  <!--  HERE  -->
               </div>
               <div class="head_Menu">
                  <!--  HERE  -->
               </div>
            </article>

            <article id="head_Note">
               <!--  HERE  -->
            </article>

         </section>
      </header>

      <aside>
         <!--  HERE  -->
      </aside>

      <footer>
         <!--  HERE  -->
      </footer>

   </body>
```

Comment: iPhone 4. Samsung 3. Have you checked for browser support? Flexbox is not support by Safari <7 and Android Browser <4.4. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex display for bigger viewports only. That way the columns won't be displayed side by side, instead, one below the other on tabs and mobiles. Doing this may help:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .row {
        display: initial !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the default properties and the vendor properties. I added `flex-wrap: nowrap` as well in order to prevent any flex-item wrapping to the side of another.

```css
@media (max-width: 40em)
{.....
  #head_Area
   {
      flex: auto;
      display: flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      border: 1px solid red;
   }
```